# How to get cardinality of relations between two tables in SQL Server using TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using following code to get all tables that have a foreign key of the table in `where` clause which in this example is `SolutionUser` :

```
select 
    (select name from sys.tables 
     where object_id = fk.parent_object_id) Name 
from 
    sys.foreign_keys fk 
left outer join 
    sys.tables st on fk.referenced_object_id = st.object_id   
where 
    st.name='SolutionUser'
```

What I can't achieve is to get the cardinality of these relationships (one-to-one, one-to-many)

Is it possible to get these cardinalities using T-SQL ?

Comment: I guess you may check  whether there is a unique constraint on the referencing side.

Comment: If you have a foreign key from table A to table B it enforces that a matching (master - "one") record must exist in B before a record (transaction - "many") can exist in A. So it indicates a many to from A to B. But it could still be a one to one. It can't be a zero or one on the B side

Answer (score 2):

This is a conceptual subject. You can't find out using schema or even data.